# Referencing passed object in _.find's context? (JS works, CS doesn't)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js

```
stream.on("emission", function(obj) {
    if (active)
    {
        var found = _.find(findable, function(o) {
            return _.contains(o.props, obj.prop);
        });

        if (typeof found !== "undefined")
        {
            console.log ("ok")
        }
    }
});
```

Works, but for instance the js2coffee.org CS conversion doesn't

```
stream.on "emission", (obj) ->
  if active
    found = _.find(findable, (o) ->
      _.contains o.props, obj.prop
    )
    console.log "ok"  if typeof found isnt "undefined"
  return
```

Yields a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined`

Can't seem to reference obj in _.find's context?

Comment: Are you sure that both versions are being called the same way? The JavaScript version of your CoffeeScript is nearly identical to your original JavaScript, the only difference is where the `var found` appears.

Comment: @muistooshort I'm fairly sure. I can actually use `""" found with JS syntax """` in the CS if I remove the var keyword, and it works.

Comment: Um, [`"""` is a multi-line string](http://coffeescript.org/#strings), not [embedded JavaScript](http://coffeescript.org/#embedded). Why don't you just look at what `obj` is at the top of the anonymous function?